# Should questions be closed if the answer is simply 'no'. Should they be answered?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, not-an-answer

So I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140042/meteor-detect-sim-phone-number)

I added a comment that the answer was 'no', it can't be done.

Now as an answer, 'no' is rubbish, and adding it as an answer in the context of SO I'd most likley get downvotes, I mean it's not even a link only answer, just a one word answer, anything after the 'no' would just be words for the sake of it.

A better answer of course would be to explain why the answer is 'no', but if 'no' is an answer, is it better to give that as an answer rather then have a question with no answers?

Is a bad answer better then no answer?

I'd argue that an answer that doesnt offer a solution is also less likley to get accepted

Comment: I don't think that question should be closed when the answer is a plain "no". It can still be a valid question. Answers should provide some background of course. I don't think that a well-explained "no"-answer will be downvoted.

Comment: If you want to bother to refer to specific reasons for no (design-based or moral-based decisions), you could augment your answer into "No and here's why."  That's much more complete.

Comment: decided to go ahead and answer the question. will be interesting to see what comments/votes it gets

Answer (score 15):

No is a powerfully valuable answer that can save the OP a vast amount of time. However, for 'no' to be useful, its needs the necessary backup so that the reader can decide to believe it. That could range from a reference to an authoritative source to an [argument from authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority).

Comment: It would be a nice addition if someone actually knew of an example question where this actually happened - there actually being a reference to backup that something indeed is not possible. I'd think it is massively unlikely, people are more invested in making things possible rather than documenting why something is impossible when it comes to technology.

Comment: I've done it with an argument from authority :-), but I don't have a link handy.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: In this case, and cases like it, I would edit the question to read "How can I do X", and leave it unanswered until such a time as an answer exists, unless "X" happens to be something that will forever be impossible in which case a "You can't do that *because*...." answer is appropriate.

---

I generally feel that if "no" is a good answer to a question, it's because the question needs to be reworded.

"No" is a good answer to questions like this:

> Is it possible to turn a user's computer off with JavaScript?

just like "Yes" is a good (well, at least appropriate) answer to questions like this:

> Is it possible to select an element from the DOM without using jQuery?

In both cases, the *intended* question isn't "is it possible", it's **how can I do it**.

Generally, I think these questions should be edited to read "**How** can I do X", at which point "No" is no longer a suitable answer. Instead, "You cannot do this because Y" becomes a valid answer, or, better, the question can remain unanswered until there *is* a solution.

Take the [question in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140042/meteor-detect-sim-phone-number). He's asking "Is there a way..." when what he's really asking is "How can I...". And yes, right now, there is no way. But that isn't to say there will *never* be a way. At one point, somebody might have asked "How can I get the user's location from their GPS in JavaScript?" and "you can't, it's impossible" would have been a valid answer. I doubt they'll ever expose an API for examining the SIM card, but it could happen, and then that question will have an answer.

Comment: I don't entirely agree. If a person has a problem _today_, a clear explanation of why they need to go shopping in 'XY' space for an alternative approach is more valuable than no answer at all.

Answer (score -3):

Yes ......................................