# How is this answer consisting only of "NO"s an answer, or am I missing something?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

I recently came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37679056/). For reference, here's the text of the answer, which also contains a graphical version of the word "NO":

> NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO

I have a hard time seeing how this is an (acceptable) answer, so I downvoted and flagged it as Not an Answer.

- Just saying "No" without any explanation is not what I would consider a good answer.
- I've looked at *[Is “this is not possible” an acceptable answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261168/is-this-is-not-possible-an-acceptable-answer)* and *[Is a sarcastic answer, a no-answer, still an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302113/is-a-sarcastic-answer-a-no-answer-still-an-answer)*, and the consensus seems to be that "No, it's not possible" is okay *with* an explanation, however, this answer has no explanation whatsoever.
- It's also comes across to me as somewhat sarcastic and unfriendly.

However, my flag was declined by a moderator with the message "*flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer*".

What am I missing? Is this a good answer? Are answers like this ("*No, it's not possible*", without an explanation) acceptable in general?

For <10k-users, here is a screenshot of the now-deleted question:

> [image]

Comment: What explanation would you expect? The answer is no. The presentation could be improved, but it's still an answer.

Comment: Had to fill in the character limit somehow.  If the answer is "No" or "It is not possible" then those are acceptable answers.

Comment: Given the idiocy of the question, this answer was clearly optimized to be most understandable to the OP.  Aim your wrath, this Q does not belong here.

Comment: You guys should loosen up. The question is so dumb it's hardly worth discussing. The answer is a joke, obviously.

Comment: Well... It's the same when a woman tells you "NO". It actually IS an answer. And you must respect it. Being short, doesn't mean it's not valuable. Imagine they ask you "Are you racist?" Perfect answer: "NO" (End Of Transmission).

Comment: @Lonnie in software development, there hardly ever is a clear-cut "no" answer. @ evan, dumb questions can get smart answers.

Comment: @CodeCaster Q: "Is xyz possible?" A: "NO"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow where the questions don't matter and everything is an answer!

Comment: @Lonnie but it is, you just don't know it.

Comment: @CodeCaster So... Q: "Is it possible to convert a ListView into a DateTimePicker?" A: "NO".

Comment: @Lonnie I'm afraid you're trying a bit too hard to be funny. And yes, you can convert a listview into a datetimepicker, if you can explain which of the listview's items you want to represents a date, and accept to lose all other items. If you're going to ask a stupid question, you get a stupid answer. My point was that pretty much any legitimate question can get a usable answer, and that "No" should always be the last resort - and if you're going to post "No" as an answer, you need to explain why not.

Comment: @Lonnie, but you can use a DateTimePicker IN a ListView, I agree with CodeCaster

Comment: @CodeCaster It was just an example. I was going to change it to a more significant one, but... this stupid FireFox crashed... again. Of course there are stupid questions that can be shut up with a simple, elegant, concise, synthetic "NO".

Comment: @Lonnie my point, again, is that in software development a lot of things are possible. Sure, you can make up a far-fetched example (_"Can I talk FTP to an HTTP server?"_) to which the answer in plain sight is _"No"_, but then still there's an underlying problem (see also: XY problem) that when clarified reveals an actual answerable problem. And yes, there are proxies that translate FTP to HTTP and/or vice versa, for example. And again, just "No" is never the answer. Or at least not an answer you should post to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Anyway, for me, "NO" is a good answer. And it is enough, in many cases.

Comment: I think this is a bad answer because the "NO" was drawn freehand in **BLACK**, when it obviously should be **RED**

Comment: **Please provide a link to the parent question, here and always**. Since the answer got deleted nearly instantly after you posted this, we have no idea of the parent question hence we can't know how well/badly a repeated 'NO' answered it.

Comment: For that questions, it looks a fantastic answer

Comment: @smci [Here's a link to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678850/is-it-possible-to-access-the-db-of-an-application-stored-in-one-mobile-from-anot). Oh wait, that doesn't help you either, because the question got nuked as well.

Comment: @smci, FYI, direct links to answers will take you to the parent question if the answer is deleted. In this case, the question was deleted too, that's why the link doesn't work.

Comment: Jon Skeet deleted the question - what more is there to discuss?

Comment: I declined your flag, and I agree with [BoltClock's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326040/2057919) 100%. I'm not going to add my own answer to repeat what several others have said, but BoltClock and others have it right: the answer you flagged *is* an answer, even though it's a lousy one. That's why I declined the NAA flag, even though it deserved deletion for other reasons.

Comment: Actually, the original question is very interesting and the possible answers manifold - ranging from peer-to-peer communication, distributed databases with individual mobiles as nodes to a simple server push-data-request to client and respective answer protocoll. No need to nuke it...

Comment: @le_m When the question is "how to do XYZ" and there are "manifold" possible answers, the question is much too broad.

Comment: @EdCottrell I can come up with manifold answers to most SO questions, but only a few are *good*. And there are surely better answers than *NO*.  If the question is too broad, then it should have been flagged as such by community decision.

Comment: @le_m First, the fact that there may be more than one answer to a question isn't what makes it too broad. Questions are too broad if "There are either *too many* possible answers, or *good answers would be too long for this format*." (emphasis added)  A "how can I do XYZ" question demonstrating zero effort and no research almost always is too broad. That's especially true of questions like the one at issue, involving multiple systems and technologies. Second, I didn't say that "NO NO NO..." was a great answer here. I'm saying the question was a bad question.

Comment: @EdCottrell I agree, so the question should have been closed as 'too broad' ('unclear' is also fine, though). I just don't see any 'idiocy' in the question or 'no' being the only answer as the majority of comment votes here indicate.

Comment: I would have considered using the "Rude or abusive" flag. I think it's disgusting that some people think this is an appropriate way to talk with other people. [It's not how you tell someone face to face, so it's not something you should be saying here.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: what do you flag for? just for using an image to say "no"? or all the answers that just saying "no"

Comment: Question was not a question, and I give the guy props for adding that personal touch of his own handwritten 'NO'.

Comment: Was the question "what are the lyrics to 2 Unlimited's biggest hit?" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkEXGgdqMz8

Comment: "Is it possible"? "No". 
"How is it not possible"? "Because you can't blah with blah and then blah the yadda with another blah."

Comment: I find it very irritating that when a user asks "Is it possible to turn iron into gold?", StackOverflow won't allow "No" for an answer, because it is too short. Often in this situation I feel frustrated that I have to pad the answer to a minimum acceptable length, and this particular answerer seems to me to be venting this frustration.

Comment: This is one of the biggest problems with StackOverflow users... the amount of elitism and patronising comments. Obviously if someone has posted a question (regardless of how stupid it is) they don't know the answer. As the saying goes, there are no stupid questions, only stupid answers. This is a stupid, lame attempt at being funny, and the only people who think it's acceptable are other elitists who want to circlejerk about how clever they are and how stupid the OP is for asking such a dumb question. Everyone starts somewhere. To simply answer "NO" like that doesn't help them learn anything.

Comment: That question was definitely unclear to say the least (although it could easily have been described without using insults, unlike some chose to do), and the very fact that it is so extremely unclear shows that the author of the "No" answer was either someone unsuccessfully trying to deal with a very bad mood day, or a genius who could understand that question that so many others deemed unclear to the point of having it deleted.

Answer (score 131):

Even if you believe the answer to any question to be "No", you need to elaborate on that - or refrain from answering altogether.

Without sources and explanation, an answer solely stating "No" is to be interpreted as *"I don't know"*. The absolute answer to some question may be a definitive "No", but if that's the only thing that the answer states, it is impossible to verify from that answer alone. And that means that in this case, it doesn't deserve the six upvotes it currently got.

The question *"How can I from app A on device X access the database of app B on device Y"* has a definitive answer, and hint, it isn't *"You can't"*.

Why your flag was declined: "No" is *an* answer. So I would vote to delete the answer, or at least get its score below 0, not only because it is wrong, but unverifiable at that.

See also [Should questions be closed if the answer is simply 'no'. Should they be answered?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303031/should-questions-be-closed-if-the-answer-is-simply-no-should-they-be-answered):

> for 'no' to be useful, its needs the necessary backup so that the reader can decide to believe it.

Comment: Only if it's a "substantive edit" you get notifications (or some code blocks were modified).

Comment: I'm sure this has come up on SO before, but I really dislike "substantative" changes being measured by character count.  I've had people edit answers to make correct code into incorrect code, but the changes were small enough that they didn't give me a notification.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler every code block edit issues a notification, be a dot or a comma.

Comment: I have a bad feeling about this. I don't know android but if *The question "How can I from app A on device X access the database of app B on device Y" has a definitive answer, and hint, it isn't "You can't".*  is true, then the actions taken here - closing a new user's question as unclear and quickly deleting it was not ideal. If the above statement holds true, then the question was definitely **very clear**, though it might have been too broad. What kind of picture does this give to a new user? That we quickly delete questions which we can't *easily* answer without giving proper reasons?

Comment: @TJ the question might be clear, but as stated it's way too broad. I may have overplayed my hand by the quoted statement, as I don't know Android that well, but there _are_ ways to implement what they were asking for, of that I'm sure.

Comment: @CodeCaster Well, the answer could the either a big "No", or a "Yes... huge article". It both ways the question was clear. Even I  (a stranger to android) understood what the user is trying to achieve. So closing the question as *unclear* followed by quick deletion (both happened within an hour) wasn't a good course of action in my opinion. It felt like "*Hey we know what you're asking for, but we're just going to act like we don't and  delete your question*". If the question was too broad, we should've closed it as *too broad* and gave some time for the OP to understand the the right reason.

Comment: @TJ the question was asked and answered a week ago, closed and deleted a day ago. The OP never bothered to respond or clarify.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yea... if one gets a big graphical "NO" and comments like "You need magic" there isn't much to respond with, but the OP took it cool and responded with *"hahaha we dont need magic... atleast tell me is there any listner to identify the change in db"* and we responded with closing as unclear and deleting the question ;) I don't know the value in keeping that question, All I was saying is, all the answers here proves that the question was *clear*.

Comment: @TJ it doesn't really matter to me whether it was closed as unclear what **exactly** they were asking or too broad. Both can apply and I don't really care which. The OP should have edited their post. I voted to delete because its current state is unsalvageable, aided through the posted answer.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that this question is a exact duplicate / repost of a previous question by the same user, so that alone is would have been a valid reason to close (and delete ?) it.

Comment: It would be tempting to suggest that "AYFR?!" would be sufficient elaboration in that case.

Comment: I am not saying the question is valid or invalid, but if closing it as too broad, it looks like the answers is "yes..." and then follow a bundles of methods

Comment: @amuse what does that mean?

Comment: In my experience, "too broad" usually means there are lots of solutions to achieve the goal, but in this case, assume the answer is correct, it is just "no"

Comment: I can´t see how "no" could be an answer on "how to do so", do you? It *could* however be an answer on "can I do this", anyway it´ll be a bad (but valid) way.

Comment: @Him those are semantics. _"How to do..."_ -> _"You can't"_ is equal to _"Can I do..."_ -> _"No"_. The case I'm arguing here is that neither _"You can't"_ nor _"No"_ are answers we want on the site, they should be _"You can't, **because**..."_ or _"No, **because**..."_

Comment: I agree, but this leads to samething basic: whilst "you can´t do this" is *syntactically* an answer to a question it is not a *valid* answer within SO. However I doubt that this difference makes it clear to SO-users and suggest to avoid to apply on this semantically approach. Having said this what we want is *semantics*, or call it *meaning*, not pure *syntax* and thus "No" or "You can´t" will never be an answer for SO.

Comment: @Him well that's the problem here: the OP flagged _"No no no"_ as Not An Answer, while it _is_ an answer. But a very, very poor one.

Comment: Than we might consider to let "no, no, no" *not* be an answer anymore making it possible to flag these kinds of answers accordingly.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - You misunderstand the definition of "answer" as regards the "Not an Answer" flag. If the post read "*Can you provide more details*", then that would be "Not an Answer". If the post read "*Great question! I had never even thought of doing that!*", then that would be "Not an Answer". If the post read "*The answer above is wrong. Don't do that.*", then that would be "Not an Answer". "No" is an answer... it addresses the question directly, it does not seek additional information and it provides advice. It's a *very* poor answer, but it's an answer by our technical definition.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/211627

Comment: If you provide an answer to a question that shouldn't be answered, and the answer technically solves the problem while also producing horrible software, as any answer would do in this case, you lose the right to ever complain about terrible software development decisions. "No" is the answer in this case, because the question itself says the 'developer' has no idea what they're doing.

Comment: @EKW I have no idea who or what you're responding to. If the answer to every question of a clueless developer would be "No", this site wouldn't have lived long.

Comment: @CodeCaster There's a difference between someone earnestly making an effort, who needs an answer to a question AFTER trying to solve the problem themselves, and a Help Vampire who has no critical thinking skills or is too lazy to use them.

Comment: @EKW oh, I may have missed the news that we're finally living in Utopia. 99% of questions initially have problems.

Comment: I thought the image provided a pretty good explanation to the text... ;)

Comment: The answer (refered to in the op, the one thats states NO) seems wrong. Surly it is possible to have interdevice communication, either via client>server>client or peer to peer. Of course the original question was way too vague, but thats not my point

Comment: @Steve I agree. An answer could have been provided to allow the OP to achieve what he wanted, even if he was asking the wrong question. An appropriate response would have been a comment asking the OP what they were trying to achieve.

Comment: @Steve I agree, see the third paragraph in this answer, or my [comments under Tim's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326031/how-is-this-answer-consisting-only-of-nos-an-answer-or-am-i-missing-something/326034?noredirect=1#comment357721_326211).

Comment: @CodeCaster oops, i completely misread your answer, it seems we agree.

Comment: I can see myself having asked such a question if new to programming, and genuinely wondering if this was possible. It could very well have been a useful answer to say something along the lines of this: "It is probably possible, but it is not a feature of any phone to offer this capability. If you need to access some data on another phone, you will probably need to write the code that exposes this data yourself and run it on that phone. It is possible to share such data over wireless or bluetooth"

Comment: @morten that is not a very good answer as well, as it doesn't show you how but just gives you a general idea of the approach, but it is way better than just "No".

Comment: @CodeCaster The question wasn't asking for how. Also, the person asking cannot possibly be told how until he decides what his needs are.If there was such a way of accessing a db, then giving us more information would be superflous, but since there isn't the most helpful we can be is to show the person what the actual limitations are.

Comment: @morten questions are, or at least should, always either implicitly or explicitly asking "How can I", not just "Can I". Otherwise the answer to 95% of questions would be simply "yes" and 5% "no", and that is not particularly useful. If the question is too vague, or not constrained enough, then it should not be answered but instead closed as unclear or too broad, and the OP should be informed through comments that they should add details.

Comment: @CodeCaster That is a good point. And I see the poster was given ample time to clarify as well.

Comment: @morten Nobody _asked_ for clarification though, maybe that's why they didn't clarify ? All they got was comments along the line of "No" and "You need magic", followed by closure and deletion of the question.

Answer (score 43):

It *is* an answer (see [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer/265553#265553) for a general explanation about answers/not-an-answers), but it is not a good answer (a good answer in this case would at least [add some explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer/265553#265553) why it is not possible - even if it is only one sentence).

I *would* flag it as 'very low quality', but that is not possible for answers with a positive score. The question itself is even more crappy, and needs to be closed as soon as possible - which <s>will probably happen</s> indeed happened because of the Meta effect.

Comment: See also the well-established: [Is "don't do it" a valid answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8893/159251) "it's a valid answer, **provided that you explain why the OP shouldn't do it**".

Comment: @JoshCaswell sorry, wrong link. Thanks!

Comment: This is the answer I was going to have to add if it didn't exist.  "Not an answer" is not "super downvote."

Comment: I kinda don't agree with the assessment that it's a bad question.  It's a _badly worded_ question, and the answer is obvious to anyone who understands how mobile phone networks work -- but that doesn't make it a bad question; in fact, it seems to me like a _good_ vehicle for delivering clue to people who _don't_ already understand mobile phone networks, because it's a relatively natural thing to _want_ to do.  (It's fairly likely that it's a duplicate, too, but that's orthogonal.)

Answer (score 26):

> How is this answer consisting only of “NO”s an answer, or am I missing something?

When Shog wrote [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/213575) there's a part that reads:

> Don't get me wrong, it's still a bad answer - **but when the question is kinda asking for bad answers this is to be expected.** Close or flag the question and move on - this is much more efficient than hanging around to babysit it by deleting every crap answer that inevitably shows up.

So, when you see a bad answer, ie. an answer consisting of nothing but "no", you have to check the question, chances are that it is as crappy as the answer is and everything should just get deleted.

Comment: So you're saying it's OK to "shitpost" under bad questions?

Comment: @CodeCaster No, it isn't. But if the question will be deleted, the answer will go with it anyway. Trying to delete the answer separately beforehand is just a waste of time, as it takes more effort but doesn't achieve a better result.

Comment: @CodeCaster No, what their saying is the question shouldn't be asked in the first place or severely improved first, so why answer it?

Comment: I mean this answer isn't actionable, it just reposts quotes from an earlier answer and adds "everything should just get deleted". @hvd that's a big "if", lots of questions that do deserve closure and deletion never get closed or deleted. Case in point: the question we're talking about here only got closed and deleted after it was mentioned on Meta. Also, without shitty answers, a question can be salvageable, so we should not ignore shitty answers.

Comment: @Lanky too late. The answer we're talking about has already been posted to a question that has already been posted, so that's a moot point. I am asking what Braiam's answer adds to this discussion, as it is unclear to me.

Comment: Seems straight-forward to me, basically we shouldn't be having this discussion in the first place as the question is the crux of the problem, deal with the question and the answers take care of themselves.

Comment: @Lanky I really don't follow, neither this answer nor your comments nor the upvotes on said comments. The question is _"What to do with answers like this"_. This answer states _"If the question is bad, the question along with its answers will be deleted"_. First that assumption is incorrect (lots of crap doesn't get deleted), second: what if it's an answer to a good question? This question is not tagged `specific-question` or `specific-answer`, so we're discussing the general case here, and this (presumably pretending to be edgy?) answer does not properly answer that question.

Comment: @Lanky or, in other words, anyone with the tiniest bit of experience can see something funny or ridiculous in simple or poorly-phrased questions. Again: so it's fine to go "shitposting" to such questions, because they'll (presumably) be deleted soon? Or is everyone here just happy to chime in because they think they finally recognize a "bad" question (which actually wasn't that bad but actually interesting, just poorly phrased and poorly researched)?

Comment: @CodeCaster I think your making too many assumptions about Braiams intent, I don't see how *"you have to check the question, **chance are** that is as crappy as the answer"* reflects what you are saying, it's just advice. They don't say "it WILL be delete" no they say "it SHOULD be", big difference.

Comment: @CodeCaster can you get your "quotes" right if you are going to quote someone? I'm not saying anything you say I do.

Comment: @Braiam not everything between quotation marks is a quote. There's this thing called paraphrasing. Can you perhaps explain what you _are_ trying to say with this answer now?

Comment: @CodeCaster the thing I'm trying to say with the answer is simple. Is in the answer. Take it as face value. Also, remember the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/213575) while reading it.

Comment: @Braiam if I understood what you are trying to say in your answer, then I wouldn't ask for clarification, would I? Your reluctance to provide me with feedback tells me enough though.

Comment: @CodeCaster what else can I clarify? Just a two sentence long using short and succinct vocabulary. There isn't any alien term nor loaned words, less archaic constructions. Maybe the problem doesn't lay on me.

Comment: @Braiam you are _very selectively_ quoting in your answer, and adding: _"you have to check the question, chances are that it is as crappy as the answer is and everything should just get deleted"_. That does not answer the OP's question: _"What am I missing? Is this a good answer? Are answers like this [...] acceptable in general?"_. At all.  So what exactly are you trying to say to the OP here? Do nothing? Leave the answer be? Vote to close the question?

Comment: @CodeCaster "Also, **remember the XY problem** while reading it." **[Read it.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/213575)** Whole. Seriously, because the exchange you had with me shows me that you are just sidestepping the main point of my answer. After you have done that read the question and my answer, again. Or just move on.

Comment: @Braiam I refer you to my earlier comments. I honestly have no idea what you're trying to say, I have no idea what you mean by the XY problem or to whom it applies in this case and I think you know very well you're actually not making any sense, proving that for me by refusing to explain your point. I am very clearly asking: what are you, as answerer, trying to say to the asker here? And it appears to be: absolutely nothing, just trying to selectively quote a popular text. That's fine, but I won't fall for it.

Answer (score 15):

What *I* don't understand is why you insist on flagging what is obviously *an answer* as "not an answer". Nowhere in the flag label or description says that it means "not a *good* answer". Those two phrases don't mean exactly the same thing. One is a *subset* of the other. Which means not every mediocre/bad answer is *not an answer*. (On the other hand, something that is not an answer cannot be a good answer in the same way that an orange cannot be a good apple because it's not an apple in the first place!)

Yes, we have standards for what counts as a passable answer to an "Is it possible to do X?" question, because saying "Yes, it is very much possible to do X." doesn't tell anyone anything other than the fact that it is possible, and likewise saying "No, it is not possible to do X." doesn't explain what exactly it is that makes X not possible, which makes such answers next to useless (unless the statement of X itself is self-explanatory). But that pertains to answers that *are answers*, which means posts that were posted as answers but are non-answers are *irrelevant to this discussion altogether*.

Which brings me to my point — granted, what we're looking at is a [shitpost](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/shitposting), i.e. an obvious attempt at deliberately making a nonconstructive post for its own sake and not a good-faith attempt at answering the question. But unless you've never asked or answered a yes/no question or your native language doesn't have a concept of yes or no, saying that no is "not an answer" to a yes/no question is downright asinine.

It's not like NAA is the *only* option for punting a post to the review queue either. And even if "very low quality" was not an option in *this specific case*, you could even have custom-flagged it explaining that the answer was obviously not a serious one and it was posted chiefly at the expense of the asker. I would be *more than happy* to remove it for that reason, *in spite of it fitting the definition of an answer in context*.

Oh and all of this is discounting the fact that the question sucks to begin with. Not that that justifies posting an intentionally bad answer at the expense of the asker, but obviously not every intentionally bad answer is posted because the question sucks — some of these time-wasting answers appear under otherwise well-written questions, too. Doesn't change the fact that "not an answer" is one of the worst choices of flag to begin with considering, again, *it's not the only option available to you*.

We have enough problems with borderline NAA flags as it is. Please don't add to them by trying to twist the definition of NAA and then complaining when your flag gets rejected afterward.

Comment: At the time of posting, the answer had a score of +4, making a VLQ flag impossible (even after a downvote).

Comment: @Glorfindel: So the OP saw fit to use NAA as a substitute. Fair enough.

Comment: In a better universe, "not a good faith attempt at answering the question" would be the guidance text for NAA :)

Comment: To be fair the description of the NAA option *still* reads "...not an answer to **the** question." The flagged answer is objectively not an answer to the question itself (though you could make the argument it is an answer to the question's title). But I'm just somebody who cares about words.

Comment: @TylerH: Not sure what the wording of the description has to do with anything. And again you can either argue about nuances till the cows come home, or just pick a better flag and spare everyone the hassle.

Comment: @BoltClock The wording of the description means that not just "any" answer will do; the answer must be an attempt to answer *the question that was asked*. I and many others have had NAA flags declined in the past because moderators have interpreted the flag instead to apply only to posts that couldn't possibly serve as an answer to *any* question about programming rather than what the description has said. Shog has acknowledged this problem on Meta, but it's quite low on their totem pole of priorities. I do agree, of course, that VLQ is a better flag in this case.

Comment: The amount of time we spend debating about the semantics and wording of "not an answer" flags... Is anyone else tired of it? Why don't we just replace all the flags with "This is a shitpost." and be done with it? We can raise our flags, you can click your delete buttons, and all will be well.

Comment: @CodyGray [been there](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+naa+flag+is%3Aq), [tried that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318952/792066), [and nope](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214583).

Comment: I've seen those questions, of course. Many of them I've voted for (except the ones that tend toward getting rid of the option to flag shitposts altogether). I don't really see where the disagreement is. It is mostly just a matter of agreeing on wording (oh god, the semantics debate again!) and getting the SE community team to agree. Unfortunately, they seem to have their hands full these days with issues other than site quality. Like rolling out new sections of the site that can quickly become riddled with quality issues.

Comment: @CodyGray well, I think that the ambiguity is deliberated. I mean, how difficult is to change "a" to something else that is less prone to interpretation.

Answer (score 7):

Many responses point out that the question *indicates a lack of fundamental understanding on the part of the original poster*. This is used as justification for the short, dismissive answer.

Sure, maybe the OP had such a confusion of ideas that their question made no sense at all. Isn't that *all the more reason* to respond with something more helpful than "NO"?

A response that *laid out the reasons behind why such a thing wouldn't be possible* would serve to reduce or eliminate the confusion of ideas. **Isn't that really the basic intent behind stackoverflow?**

Answer (score 6):

For all this debating on which form of no, the answer is actually "Yes", but requires a rooted device.

Obviously my given answer is hardly better than the repeated No, but that's not the point of meta.

In this case, perhaps the best answer really is No, unless some strange caveat, or Yes with same strange caveat, where the caveat needs to be well-explained.

Comment: Maybe, but it doesn't necessarily mean that root is necessary. If the app you want to get data from _wants you to do so_ (and the fact that he's using content providers strongly suggests so), you can. I'm pretty sure this is a case of the XY problem, and that the OP does not actually want or need direct access to the database, but just wants the data. (see [CodeCaster's comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326031/how-is-this-answer-consisting-only-of-nos-an-answer-or-am-i-missing-something/326298#comment357724_326211)).

Comment: You and CodeCaster may well be right; however it's also possible he wants to spy on another app that doesn't want him to. That's how bad the question is that we can't tell.

Answer (score 5):

That answer totally missed the mark.

Here's my version:

[image: No.]

In all seriousness, you have to consider the context of the question. Ordinarily, we *do* expect that folks will back up "this simply isn't possible" with an explanation that tells the person why. Answers involving the same origin policy in browsers are a good example of "This is why that's never going to work" and they're often augmented with "But thinking about your design in this manner would obviate the problem."

This example and context is much closer to outright lunacy than anything else, so I consider the answer *in that context* to be extremely well-tempered, light hearted and, well, helpful. But I'm not convinced that the question was serious to begin with. I wouldn't have bothered to answer, but I admire the restraint on behalf of the user that did - half expected at least one person to have called the OP a name or three. If there's any fault here it's probably feeding a troll.

In short - kind of bad example, but worth reiterating that we do expect serious questions to receive serious answers, which means explaining 'no' whenever possible.

I'm pretty sure this wasn't a serious question, at least I hope not :)

Comment: I'm not someone who tries to see the beauty in questions like the one we're discussing here. I am honestly amazed though by the responses to this issue altogether. Is it because it is so easy to say _"You want to let two different apps on two different devices access each other's data? Hah! That's ludicrous! Outrageous! Even a child knows you can't do that!"_, or what is it? Yes, the phrasing was done poorly, the research absolutely absent, the question should have been closed as "unclear", but am I the only one who is genuinely curious to what problem the OP actually was trying to solve?

Comment: I mean I really suspect all the naysayers to have never done anything else in their career than building mobile apps. To me it is obvious that the OP of said question was looking to some kind of publish-subscribe pattern (one app produces, the other consumes), but that they were not experienced enough to know about that term, nor about how to think outside their very small and limited app box, so their Y for the obvious XY problem here was _"I know, I must go and dig in the other app's database!"_. But that's just me.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is not appropriate because it doesn't elaborate on why it's incorrect. It should include additional clarification, like:

[image]

Comment: Good point. This additional clarification is essential for people who don't speak English well and may have trouble understanding complex language.

Comment: @Cody Gray: What if the gesture depicted means something completely different to what the answerer intended to those people?

Comment: @BoltClock You mean, the guy is holding up the wrong finger here?

Comment: A finger wag with the finger in question instead would be powerful indeed.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, that is an appropriate answer.  However, the response was a touch unprofessional (but hilarious).

The question asked "is it possible..." and the poster got the answer to that question.  Others marked that it was a poor question. I don't think it's necessarily a poor question.  Sometimes you need to ask a question that only requires a one word answer.  Asking "Is it possible to..."? could either be a time-saver for research, or a starting point for new tech development.

It could also just be a poorly worded question. The simple answer "NO" could help the OP uncover what their actual question is.

Comment: You are wrong..

Comment: (Do you find that to be an appropriate, helpful response?)

Comment: Yes i do find that appropriate @JoshCaswell  If i ask "does 1+1=2?" a simple yes or no answer will suffice.  I don't need volumes of mathematical theories to explain the answer.

Answer (score -7):

NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO

---

But seriously, it's because [we hate fun on Stack Overflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)

Comment: It's not about hating fun. It's about hating answers that are severely lacking in useful information.

Comment: @skrrgwasme http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/213575

Comment: No, I love fun.

Comment: "NO NO NO NO NO NO" is an incorrect answer to the OP's question.  Amusingly, "YES YES YES YES YES YES YES" is a correct, if poor, one, as the OP is indeed "missing something".  Please correct your answer, thx.

Comment: I wonder if that article by Jeff in 2010 has any significance today

Comment: @gldraphael By and large, it's best significance today is its frequent reference, as here; in order to point out that we *don't* hate fun. Not entirely, at least.

Comment: @Yakk NO NO NO NO NO N.... meh, you get the idea...