# Answer deleted for not answering question, but it did

Tags: discussion, review-queues, deleted-answers, specific-answer

Yesterday, I made an answer on a post stating that what OP was asking was not possible using current APIs (specific to Chrome). A couple hours later, another user commented on my answer stating that I had failed to answer the question, and I should be more careful in the future. I responded to them stating that I had in fact answered the question at hand, as I stated the original question was not possible (which, by the way, was also explicitly asked in the original question).

I fail to see why my answer was deleted, and I'm unable to even view the answer any more. It would be great if there was a notification that an answer of mine has been deleted (and why!), as without it I am left wondering what happened.

Hopefully someone with enough reputation can pull up the answer I'm talking about, and perhaps explain things to me.

Edit: [Here's the answer in question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45340630/2718801)

Comment: `I'm unable to even view the answer any more.` You can always view your own deleted answers.

Comment: It's not showing up on my profile, and I don't remember the exact post. That's probably a better way of describing it.

Comment: Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2718801/jhpratt?tab=answers) and on the bottom there should be a checkbox that says *show recently deleted*.  Check that and it should show up

Comment: You may still be able to see the notification of the comment on the post in your notification feed, and it may be in your browser's history, if you're still on the same computer.

Comment: Ok, looking at the comments that were left (which I never saw the notifications for, as it was deleted quickly thereafter), the user mentions that I should've linked to documentation or external resources. However, the feature doesn't exist, so why would there be documentation for it?

Comment: *A couple hours later, another user commented on my answer stating that I had failed to answer the question* I don't know if it's what happened in your specific case, but it's possible that user thinks that a technically wrong answer is the same as a post being Not An Answer (which is incorrect). I see a lot of legitimate attempts to answer with a similar comment on it in the Low Quality Posts queue.

Comment: Can you post a link to the answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45340630/2718801

Comment: @jhpratt Since the comment was from review, you *will* have seen a notification for it, even though the post was deleted.

Comment: That's what I would've thought, but I didn't receive a notification.

Comment: @BSMP In this case it's not arguing that the answer is wrong, but that it's so lacking in information and support for its assertion as to be of no value, which is at least potentially valid as a reason for a post being VLQ.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326031/how-is-this-answer-consisting-only-of-nos-an-answer-or-am-i-missing-something

Answer (score 20):

Here's what your answer said:

> As far as I'm aware, this is not currently possible. Your use case sounds quite useful, though!

You're right, it does answer the question. But the conversational nature of the second sentence might have thrown reviewers off (even though it's quite obviously not a request for clarification or a separate question, despite what the canned comments claim). This is why we try to avoid chit-chat in answers where possible.

One of the reviewers says that you should back up your claim. While that is true, that doesn't warrant deleting your answer.

That being said, I don't recommend undeleting it until you believe you can flesh it out. It's not a very compelling answer at the moment, especially given the bounty on the question, and will only attract downvotes if left up in its current state. (Perhaps review was doing you a favor by getting your answer deleted sooner rather than later after all.)

You don't need a very lengthy and detailed answer though, just one that's specific. Here are some examples of bounties I've earned with answers amounting to "this is not possible for the following reason":

- [Is it possible via CSS 3 to set the color of text in an element using the text content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829397/is-it-possible-via-css-3-to-set-the-color-of-text-in-an-element-using-the-text-c/7830176#7830176)
- [Data URI link <a href="data: doesn't work in Microsoft Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33154646/data-uri-link-a-href-data-doesnt-work-in-microsoft-edge/33197664#33197664)
- [::first-letter selector - IE11 has a different layout compared to Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032360/first-letter-selector-ie11-has-a-different-layout-compared-to-firefox/37108065#37108065)

Comment: Per backing up the claim, how can this be done for an API that doesn't exist?

Comment: @jhpratt: Good question. It should suffice to state that the API simply doesn't exist - it's at least more specific than "this is not possible". You can also link to what you think may be relevant documentation and point out the lack of such an API where you would expect to find it (though YMMV on how convincing this will be).

Comment: @jhpratt: I fished up some of my previously earned bounties to give you an idea of what's acceptable.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @BoltClock I believe i was one of the 'flaggers' in this case. I wanted to see exactly what you're specifying- an attempt at documentation or an implied research attempt. I failed to see how that answer was beneficial, but this clarification of the flag helps me. How fitting that i should stumble upon this in meta:)

Answer (score 18):

To me your answer is more a comment then an answer and I would have voted to delete it as well

> As far as I'm aware, this is not currently possible

Isn't really an answer.  You could take a stand and go

> Currently it is not possible to do this.

Or, it might actually be possible and you can have

> Sure you can do this ... and detail the answer here

But your answer just says that with what you know it is not but maybe someone will know more and actually will be able to tell you, which to me can be done with a comment.

Comment: Perhaps I should've clarified I'm very familiar with Chrome's APIs?

Comment: @jhpratt I don't think you need to do that but I do think you should take a stand.  If it is not possible then say so, that is a valid answer.  The way it is worded right now makes it sound more like a guess then a statement.

Comment: Ok, so try and be more assertive with the answer? I intentionally left it worded the way it was as I'm not 100% on all the APIs, but then again no one really is.

Comment: @jhpratt I understand but it is okay to wind up being wrong.  Take a stand and if later we find out there is some way to do it you can delete the answer then.

Comment: Fair enough. To me, it just seems like I should show the slight uncertainly rather than definitively say something. Though it that's what SO wants, then so be it.

Comment: @jhpratt It's what I want but I could be wrong.  I by no means speak for the community.  How this answer is received by the community will tell you how other feel.

Comment: Well, that's certainly true. With the limited sample size of 1 here, it seems as though you're with the majority.

Comment: i agree with this, i was an original flagger and it did seem more like a guess to me. I read it as there was a lack of research done and, therefore, a lack of knowledge.

Comment: @Jason Ok, should I edit it and undelete or just leave it as is?

Comment: I would edit it if that truly is the correct answer (i honestly do not know) but i would take boltclock's advice and make it presentable.