# Answering a (maybe) too localized question with links to comments

Tags: discussion, comments, specific-question, specific-answer, link-only-answers

Recently I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52728226/5247200) about a jQuery plugin not working as expected.

The problem was extremely simple: the OP dind't realize that the library requires a license he doesn't own.

I understand that the question is unlikely to help anyone in the future, so I wondered if I should flag the question as "*should be closed...*". I was unsure and there were more experience users around at that moment, so I just pointed out the problem in a comment a let it go.

I came back to the question when the OP pinged me in a comment. It was not closed and got no answers so I decide to put together the info provided in my comments as an answer. The OP accepted it.

Some hours later my answer was deleted by a moderator for being link-only. I thought that links were OK because they pointed to comments in the very same question, so there is no risk that they become unavailable. Also, IMHO, the answer was clear even stripping out the links.

I guess that was a wrong assumption, so I edit the answer to provide context for the links. When I was done, I flag it as in need for moderator intervention:

> I fixed this answer (considered link-only). I kindly request for undeletion.

The only feedback that I got so far is a downvote.

Because just 10k+ users can see deleted posts it is clear that a very experienced user thinks that the answer is wrong even after the update. But I am honestly confused about the reasons.

#### Some context:

A couple of weeks ago I started to work more often with the review queues. To see one of my answers deleted (and mainly without really understanding why) somehow disempowers me for the task.

I'd really like to have some feedback about how I acted wrongly. Some ideas:

The question was too localized so I...

- should have flag it.
- shouldn't have answered. A comment with the solution was enough.

But in the above cases, why the question has not gathered downvotes neither has been closed?

- There's nothing wrong with the question, my answer is just poor.

---

The answer is deleted, so I leave a screen-shot as reference:

[image]

Comment: "I thought that links were OK because they pointed to comments in the very same question, so there is no risk that they become unavailable." Note that comments can be deleted at any time. If your comment is deleted then the link is broken.

Comment: Future readers won't want to go through this bunch of comments trying to understand what the answer is talking about. Converting your comment as a proper answer is perfectly fine, moreover when a discussion was needed to come to the correct solution, but once the answer is posted, it should be self-contained and the comments become "No longer needed".

Comment: To provide an example of you could "conserve" the comments in a useful way, have a look at [this community-wiki answer by me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47471376/4733879). I did it like that to (1) keep the comments, even if they get deleted and (2) *to provide future readers the fastest way to a solution*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The original answer was flagged for being low quality, so a moderator deleted it, rather justified I'd say. The improved answer is a lot better, so I undeleted it.

In general, "too localised" isn't a thing anymore; we tried that, but then abandoned it. If the question is clear and answerable, that's fine. The only kind of "too localised" questions we close are typos and syntax errors, since those are of no use whatsoever typically. But a missing licence key is something other users may encounter. To that end, it'd be good if the question could be improved so it's easier to quickly correlate that specific symptom with that specific solution.

Comment: Good to know about the "too localized" thing. As I commented in the question, my concern was, beyond this specific situation, how to act in the review queues. Now I know it a little better. Stackoverflow is an old community with a complex and evolving culture. It gets time to manage all the rules that can make you useful member. BTW, as suggested, I have edited the title of the linked question to improve searchability.

Comment: In the good old days, a mod would use "convert to comment".  Is this perhaps no longer possible when you get this because of a flag?  Should that be fixed?

Comment: @Hans The answer was really a summary of existing comments. Not much use converting that to a comment.

Comment: "Justified low quality?" I am inclined to disagree. If you strip *all* the links out and leave only the readable text we get "The plugin you are using requires a license key. You don't have one." which [*is* an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303032/1663383). The [presentation might need work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326031/how-is-this-answer-consisting-only-of-nos-an-answer-or-am-i-missing-something/326071#comment356595_326031), but it *is* an answer.

Comment: "...since those are of no use whatsoever typically." I would add "other than to the OP".

Comment: Is it "a lot better"? The entire comment section should be cleaned as "no longer needed" (why would it be needed if it was converted to an answer?). The answer has too many useless links IMO

Comment: @deceze I think "_too localize_" close reason is still there, it is hidden into "_this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_" ..?

Comment: @Teemu At least that's better defined and limited to "typo" and "can't be reproduced anymore". It's not allowing for subjective judgement like "ain't  nobody gonna need this" as the old "too localised" did.

Comment: Well, I've seen this used as a reason to close a question without typos or "can't be reproduced" quite often. In practice, everything the close vote reason says, can and will be used against the poor questions.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - "The entire comment section should be cleaned as 'no longer needed'". Agree. No because they are included in the answer (just 2 out of 14 are), but because they are mostly conversational and no longer needed. I've requested a purge. "The answer has too many useless links IMO". Also agree, it has been edited. But, since they didn't compromise legibility, I don't think it was a reason to downvote. Let alone to keep the answer deleted.

Answer (score 3):

There are actually two questions here:

- if the referenced question is "too localized"
- if the link(-to-comments)-only answer is a proper one.

*@deceze* has already answered both, but I want to go deeper into the second one.

Since I posted this question I have spent some time reading Meta. Now I have a different standpoint:

*Answers must be **self-contained**.

The fact that a contextless link points to a comment doesn't make it **any better**.*

When I first answered the referenced question I thought: "*Why to include information that is already available in the comments when I can just link it?*". It turned out that things work exactly the other way around: if the info is relevant to the answer it must be included there. Doing so makes the comment unnecessary and it should be deleted.

[A guide to moderating comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237978/404453) has been very enlightening.

> #### When should I flag a comment?
>
> When it will be shown to future readers but offers them nothing of value.
>   [...]
>
> - **rude or abusive** [...]
> - **no longer needed** covers a wide variety of different comments, including:
>
>   - Obsolete comments. They served a purpose once upon a time but no longer: requests for clarification that've been addressed via edits, suggestions for improvement that were long ago heeded, etc. [...]
>   - Chatty comments. [...] these are pretty benign - right up until they're being shoved in the face of every reader two years later. [...]
>   - Jokes, "thank you", etc. - not necessarily harmful in the moment, but distracting and annoying after the fact.
> - **in need of moderator intervention** [...]
>
> [...] if most or all of an entire comment thread needs to go, just flag the post itself and suggest that it be purged.

> #### Archiving a completed conversation
>
> Sometimes a conversation can be useful in understanding the history of a post, but not terribly important otherwise for future readers. To remove the distraction, move the comments to chat, delete them, and then edit the resulting comment to point to the transcript rather than the chat room.

Some comments to this post where pointing in that direction:

> Note that comments can be deleted at any time. If your comment is deleted then the link is broken.

> The entire comment section should be cleaned as "no longer needed"

> Once the answer is posted, it should be self-contained and the comments become "No longer needed"

I have read again all the comments under this new (for me) perspective to find out that **not a single one is needed any longer**. Actually, I **flagged** the question accordingly, so it is **purged or moved to chat**.

All that links (already removed) in my answer would have become **broken**.

I still think that, in this case, the first version of the answer could be "poor but enough" even after stripping out all the links. Anyway, "poor but enough" shouldn't be the goal.