# Is this really considered as an answer?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, specific-answer

I find disturbing that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2123202/4197505) answer to this question ([Can Google Chrome open local links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087894/can-google-chrome-open-local-links)) is the one that received the most upvotes.

My first thinking reading this was: **this is not an answer and should be a comment**.

Why? because it doesn't answer the question, it is vague, it is not detailed, it doesn't help at all.

Nevertheless it got 47 upvotes. I think the only reason such answer received 47 upvotes is because it is 10 years old, and in 2010 SO didn't have the same standards as now.

I then flagged it as "not an answer", downvoted it, and let a comment to express my felling to the answerer.

But then, I wondered if I was right at all, I was just basing my judgement on my own experience on SO and instinct. So I took 10 minutes to find related guidelines and questions on meta. And after 10 minutes, I still don't know if I am right or wrong. I came to 2 meta (SO and Exchange) discussions that serve a bit as reference regarding this matter, and are in opposition according to me.

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/4197505) clearly state that I was wrong. According to it, it is an answer and should not have been flagged as "not an answer".

However [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226142/274492), shows that I am right.

> Answers need to have sufficient information to understand the answer.
> The answer should be described in a reasonable level of detail and /
> or include a minimal example of the answer.

So, am I right or wrong?

Comment: I suppose the downvotes are to tell me that I am wrong. That's fine :) However if you don't say why I am wrong, then I can't fix myself and properly deal with this in the future. I am expecting guidelines here.

Comment: You're wrong. It actually does answer the question - you can't get it to work in Chrome because it's disabled for security reasons. That is an answer. Any workarounds are also answers (assuming it follows the other rules of course), but it's still _an_ answer

Comment: you can always downvote it, if you don't like it. I think it somewhat on the short sode, but that much can't be told anyway

Comment: @honk if you have read my question then you should ,know that I have read that post, which shows that I am wrong in my flagging. However I am here because I am still doubtful about the validness of the answer, maybe I should have flagged it as a "poor answer".

Comment: @zoe is an answer stating an OBVIOUS thing in only one sentence , a good answer at all ??? Its perfectly obvious that this was disabled for security reason, as chrome produce a  ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT error.  My concern is that it receives 47 upvotes without even answering the question. That is awful for Stackoverflow principles according to me.

Comment: There is no "poor answer" flag, as far as I know. If you think an answer is not useful, just downvote and move on.

Comment: It might be obvious to you, but that doesn't make it universally obvious. Far from everyone can apply logical reasoning to understand error messages, so it actually is helpful for some people. It not being helpful for you isn't a deletion reason

Comment: This post may be of interest: [Is “this is not possible” an acceptable answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261168/is-this-is-not-possible-an-acceptable-answer) also [Should questions be closed if the answer is simply 'no'. Should they be answered?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303031/should-questions-be-closed-if-the-answer-is-simply-no-should-they-be-answered)

Comment: And [Are answers that say that the question is unsolvable not answers? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366302/are-answers-that-say-that-the-question-is-unsolvable-not-answers) *(there are at least three duplicates for that meta question?)*

Comment: *is an answer stating an OBVIOUS thing in only one sentence* --> well, it's not for me, learned a new thing today. .

Comment: *...as chrome produce a ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT error...* @ThomasG But that part isn't in the question. If the question itself actually said, "Google Chrome doesn't allow file:/// links in pages that aren't also file:/// for security reasons", then that answer would just be repeating information and your objection would make sense. As written, it's not clear that the OP knows that this is a security issue.

Answer (score 9):

**Short version**

You probably have too high a standard for what the answer is. As per your points:

1. Doesn't answer the question -> it does (it is impossible to use the protocol).
2. Doesn't help at all -> it does (at least 49 people found it helpful enough).
3. It is vague -> no, it is not (see [definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vague)). It is very clear.
    Although the "security reasons" part makes it not detailed (see #4).
4. It is not detailed -> true, but it does not make it less of an answer.

**On comment answers**

On the one hand, this is an answer:

> You can't because of <insert reason>

On the other hand, this should be a comment<sup>0</sup>:

> I think your code works fine

What's the difference between the two? The second one *is not verifiable* without a response from the OP, while the first one is standalone and can be referenced by other answers as the source.

**On NAA flagging**

The answer qualifies for *formal definition* of being one ("How can I?" -> "You can't"). It may not be a *good* answer, or, to be more precise, not a *detailed* answer, though. The Über Meta answer you linked to is an opinion of a user, not the consensus (if any, you should look at the question as [an official statement by Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342031/786798) at the time).

A simple real-world example is being deemed [legally incompetent](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/incompetence) - you can't be deemed as such for being a *bad* person, but only for being one *incapable* of being responsible for your actions.

**On undeserved credit**

The answer got 49 upvotes (and 4 downvotes) by now, and that means that ~4.5 people found it useful every year - that is a natural progression for an answer to a popular question. It simply means that this number of people *found it useful* (as they might - knowing that something is impossible is a time-saver).

**What you can do**

Listed in order of potentially positive impact:

1. Post a [canonical answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992/what-is-a-canonical-question-answer-and-what-is-their-purpose) yourself
2. Edit a community wiki found there to bring it into shape
3. Upvote other answers to promote *useful* ones
4. Ask the answerer to expand on it - they are still active

Finally, downvote the answer if you don't feel like doing any of the above.

---

<sup>0</sup> The example is taken from just yesterday, flagged as NAA, confirmed.